# What Happens to Partition After Ubuntu Installation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows, ntfs, ext4

I'm currently installing Linux on my laptop. It has 3 partitions (C, D and E). I want to install Ubuntu on C completely getting rid of windows. D and E partitions have data that I would like to keep (storing them elsewhere isn't an option at the moment)

I've selected the "do not use partition" option for D and E during installation.  I've spent the past 30 minutes googling but can't seem to find a useful answer. So before I proceed, I wanted to know what would happen to the partitions. Will I still have full access to them? Will the data inside them remain untouched?

Answer (score 1):

If you set them as "do not use partition" they won't be touched at all.

If I remember correctly, you can still select a mount point for them, so that a line for each is added to your fstab file (this way they will be mounted automatically, e.g. set mount points to /myfiles1, /myfiles2).

Anyway, before you install Ubuntu, I'd suggest you back up your disk, if that is not possible, at least back up your Widows install, you never know when and if you will need it.